# How to remove key but keep childs

Tags: json, scala, json4s

I'm new to Scala and I'm trying to process json document.
I'm using scala 2.13.3 with the following librairies :

```scala
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.0" % "test"
libraryDependencies += "org.json4s" %% "json4s-native" % "3.6.9"
```

The problem is that I can't find a way to remove a key and still keep his children as follows:

**Here's the json document to begin with:**

```
{
  "Key": {
    "opt": {
      "attribute1": 0,
      "attribute2": 1,
      "attribute3": 2
    },
    "args": {
      "arg1": 0,
      "arg2": 1,
      "arg3": 2
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to remove the `"Key"` to keep only his children `"opt"` and `"args"` so that I get the Json document below :

```
{
  "opt": {
    "attribute1": 0,
    "attribute2": 1,
    "attribute3": 2
  },
  "args": {
    "arg1": 0,
    "arg2": 1,
    "arg3": 2
  }
}
```

---

### My code

I use the `Json4s` library to manipulate documents, there is a `transformField` operator that allows to perform operations on fields `(key, value) => (key, value)`. So I tried to define an empty key `""` but it doesn't answer my need. I also tried to return only the associated value but the partial function doesn't allow it.

**Here is my scala code :**

```scala
val json: JObject =
  "Key" -> (
    "opt" -> (
      ("attribute1" -> 0) ~
        ("attribute2" -> 1) ~
        ("attribute3" -> 2)
      ) ~
      ("args" -> (
        ("arg1", 0) ~
          ("arg2", 1) ~
          ("arg3", 2)
        )))

val res = json transformField {
  case JField("Key", attr) => attr
}

println(pretty(render(res)))
```

unfortunatly I can't just use `transformField` to transform `("Key", attr)` into `attr`.

---

Is there an easy way to remove the `"Key"` key from my Json while keeping its children `"opt"` and `"args"`?

Comment: BEWARE: Json4s is [vulnerable under DoS/DoW attacks](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+denial)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usually better to convert JSON to Scala objects, manipulate the Scala objects, and then convert back to JSON.

This is what it might look like  using `jackson`:

```
import org.json4s.{DefaultFormats, Extraction}
import org.json4s.jackson.{JsonMethods, Serialization}

val jsonIn = """
  {
    "Key": {
      "opt": {
        "attribute1": 0,
        "attribute2": 1,
        "attribute3": 2
      },
      "args": {
        "arg1": 0,
        "arg2": 1,
       "arg3": 2
     }
   }
 }
"""

case class Opt(attribute1: Int, attribute2: Int, attribute3: Int)
case class Args(arg1: Int, arg2: Int, arg3: Int)
case class Key(opt: Opt, args: Args)
case class DataIn(Key: Key)

implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

val dataIn: DataIn = Extraction.extract[DataIn](JsonMethods.parse(jsonIn))

val jsonOut: String = Serialization.write(dataIn.Key)
```

In this case the Scala processing is just extracting the `Key` field from the `DataIn` class.

I am on Scala 2.12 so YMMV.